# Updating WSO2 EMM Policies and publishing to iOS devices via REST Console

Tags: ios, wso2, wso2-iot

Using version 2.0.1 of the EMM, I am using the console API to programtically add the user to an existing policy and publish that policy to the device.  Reading the API docs, I believe the order to be the following:

```
GET (/mdm-admin/policies/{id}) <---  This is working.
```

Update the policy JSON with the registered device owning user.

```
PUT (/mdm-admin/policies/{id}) <---  This works as well. 
PUT (/mdm-admin/policies/apply-changes) <---  API returns 200
```

The following issues come to the forefront.

> ```
> 1) The Policy pack is never pushed to the device.
> 2) The restriction placed into the policy disappears from the policy.
> ```

Am I missing a step in the process to force that push to occur, and should I be pushing the entire policy or just the changed list of users?

Answer (score 0):

"The restriction placed into the policy disappears from the policy."
Is a know intermittent issue in EMM 2.0.1 and you can prevent that issue by editing the policy after creating and check the restrictions are in order.If not do modify/include those restrictions and save the policy.

This is the best and out of the box work around possible.